# How to Create a pattern for URL parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I wrote this code in file `RouteServiceProvider.php` that is located in `app/Providers` directory.

In method boot:

```
$this->pattern('{id}', '[0-9]+');
```

then according to what I read, I thought if I write this code:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id){
    return $id;
});
```

in file web.php in routes directory the id parameter accept just int value, but when i test this url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/a` I saw `a` is returned.

Where is the problem and how can I make pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters) you should use `Route::` facade instead of  `$this->` and `id` instead of `{id}`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```